# CORS error coming when call Ajax GET request to My API with token

Tags: ajax

I am not able to resolved Cors issue in ajax GET request ,
I have a api  i want to get data from there using GET request but it's giving cors error
can anyone please help? below is my code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Start"); 
        
      //get user details
        
        function getUser() {
            var token = 'bdbc6fc9d9c3867b23329b69c22b6751';
            $.ajax({
                url:'https://staging.mobikasa.com/landingpage/landingpage/career_api.php?searchstring=kalp&currentpage=1&limit=5',
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'application/json',
                headers: {"Authrization": 'Bearer ' + token},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                   
                    
                },
                
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log("Something error")
                }
            })
        }
                      
    // Call getUser function
        getUser();
    });
```

Comment: "Authrization" should be "Authorization". Otherwise, please post the error message.

Comment: @CarstenHagemann thnaks, Now no any error.